# Showing this is analytic and finding its derivative $f(z)= \frac{4z+1}{z^3 - z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show the following is analytic and find it's derivative?
$$f(z)= \frac{4z+1}{z^3 - z}$$

I am having trouble solving the above, since I am not sure how to break this into terms of $u,v$ for my Cauchy riemann equations, perhaps there is an alternative strategy?

Domain is $\mathbb C \ \{0,1,-1\}$

---

If I just derive it I obtain $-1-8 z+3 z^2+16 z^3$. However I am not sure how to show it is analytic, or if this is even right.

Comment: How could the derivative be a polynomial? That would mean $f$ is a polynomial, which it isn't. What's wrong with the quotient rule?

Answer (score 0):

This is an
[assignment question](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/courses/MATH3401/Tutorials/hwk3.pdf), so hints only please.

One approach would be to use a partial fraction decomposition and show that it is a sum of functions which are analytic on the domain.